# How to do calculation on one class and output the answer on another class

Tags: java, class, bubble-sort

sorry to repost this question again but I really need the answer.

What I need is to get the answer to the bubble list (on one class) to appear on another class, as shown below:

```
public class BubbleSort4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int intArray[] = new int[]{5,90,35,45,150,3};

            System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
            for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
            {
                    System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
            }

            bubbleSort(intArray);

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
            for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
            {
                    System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
            }

      }

     private static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray) 
     {                            
            int n = intArray.length;
            int temp = 0;

            for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
            {
                    for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
                    {

                            if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j])
                            {

                                     temp = intArray[j-1];
                                    intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                                    intArray[j] = temp;
                            }

                    }
            }    
    }

}
```

And get the answer to the above coding to appear on OddArr3:

> System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : " +
>   bubbleSort.sortBubble(intArray));

System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : " + bubbleSort.sortBubble(intArray)); does not seem to work.

Below is the full coding to OddArr3

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

public class OddArrSe3:
{
     public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        int[] array_sort = {10,41,21,24,34,15,40,12,32,23,13,25,30,31,22,33,14,35,20,11};

        ArrayList<Integer> OddArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> EvenArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i : array_sort)    
        {
            if ((i & 1) == 1) 
            {
                OddArr.add(i);
            } 
            else 
            {
                EvenArr.add(i);
            }
         }

         Collections.sort(OddArr);
         Collections.sort(EvenArr);
         System.out.println("Odd:" + OddArr);
         System.out.println("Even:" + EvenArr);

          int OddArr2[] = {11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 25, 31, 33, 35, 41};
          int toSearch = 31;  

          int EvenArr2[] = {10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24, 30, 32, 34, 40};
          int toSearch2 = 32;

          LinearSearch4 linearSearch = new LinearSearch4();  
          BinarySearch4 binarySearch = new BinarySearch4();  
          Bubblesort4 bubblesSort = new BubbleSort4();

          System.out.println("Linear Search Index : "  
          + linearSearch.searchLinear(OddArr2, toSearch));  
          System.out.println("Binary Search Index : "  
          + binarySearch.searchBinary(EvenArr2, toSearch2)); 
          **System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : " + bubbleSort.sortBubble(intArray));**
        }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. First of all, where is intArray in OddArrSe3 class??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to output answer from 2 classes (OddArrSe3 and BubbleSort4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483558/how-to-output-answer-from-2-classes-oddarrse3-and-bubblesort4)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question. Your method should be public, not private. Then you can access it.

I have also two remarks:

- First of all, why do you have two `main` methods? In small prorgrams you usually need one just to start the program.
- In addition try to NOT use names for classes/methods like `OddArr2`/
  `OddArrSe3`. They make code less understandable.

Answer (score 0):

1) please remove the colon after the class name 'OddArrSe3'
2) As Marcin Szymczak pointed out, two main methods are not required.
3) change the signature  of method bubbleSort to public int[]  bubbleSort(int[] intArray) and return intArray after sorting. (private methods are not accessible outside the class in which they are declared)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. but I do not really understand step 5. –  user3082700 yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a static method from an instance. It should be `BubbleSort4.bubbleSort(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes and re try

1. Remove `:` from `OddArrSe3:`
2. Make your `BubbleSort4.bubbleSort()` method `public`
3. call `BubbleSort4.bubbleSort(array_sort);` to short your array
4. `BubbleSort4.bubbleSort()` method is `void` it will give compilation error if you call it as follows:

   ```
   System.out.println ("Bubble Sort : "+BubbleSort4.bubbleSort(array_sort));
   ```
5. Either change return type of your method as `public int[] bubbleSort()` and return sorted array or use a `for` loop to traverse your array and print the sorted numbers

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. but I do not really understand step 5.